# Understanding groups of order 12 as it appears in Dummit.

Tags: group-theory, semidirect-product

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Question 1.** Why the homomorphism $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ give rise to isomorphic semidirect product?

From what i see, $\varphi_2=\varphi_1^2$ then $(V\rtimes_{\varphi_1} T)\simeq (V\rtimes_{\varphi_1^2} T)$

What is the explicit isomorphism in this case? Well, I can't see how to relate $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$ with said isomorphism.

**Question 2.** Why in this case the only non-abelian group is $A_4$?

I know that the semi-direct product is non-abelian when the homomorphism is non-trivial, but why in this case must the group be isomorphic to $A_4$?

**Question 3**. Finally in the last part, I can't see how Dummit finds the homomorphisms that are mentioned.
I have the following (written not rigorously):

$V=\langle a\rangle\times \langle b\rangle$, $T=\langle \lambda\rangle$

I need find the homomorphism $\varphi:V\to \text{aut}(T)$

$|V|=4$ then $|\ker(\varphi)|\in \left\{1,2,4\right\}$ then $\ker(\varphi)=\left\{1,\langle a\rangle, \langle b\rangle, \langle ab\rangle\right\}$

**(I)** If $\ker(\varphi)=\langle ab\rangle$ then $\varphi(ab)=\lambda^2$ (because $\lambda^2$ is the identity in $\mathbb{Z}_2.$

Now, $\varphi(ab)=\varphi(a)\varphi(b)$ (homomorphism) then  $\varphi(a)\varphi(b)=\lambda^2$ implies that $\varphi(a)=\varphi(b)=\lambda$ (obtaining the homomorphism mentioned by dummit in a not so rigorous way)

Therefore, $\varphi_1(a)=\lambda$ and $\varphi_1(b)=\lambda$ has kernel $\langle ab\rangle.$

Why ab centralizes $T$? I have the following: If $T=\langle y\rangle$, $y^3=1$

$(ab)\cdot y=\varphi(ab)(y)=\lambda^2(y)=y$ (because $\lambda^2=Id$)

then $ab y (ab)^{-1}=y$ i.e. $aby=yab $therefore $ab$ centralizes $T$. This is right?

**(II)** If $\varphi_2$ and $\varphi_3$ have kernels $\langle a\rangle$, $\langle b\rangle$  repectively. Why the three semidirect products are all isomorphics  to $S_3\times \mathbb{Z}_{2}$?

Again I cannot see the explicit isomorphism between the semi-direct products.

Comment: The proof in the book explains clearly why the semidirect products in Question 1 are isomorphic. The isomorphism interchanges $y$ and $y^2$ and is the identity on $V$. As for Question 2, this follows from the fact that $A_4$ is also a semidirect product of this type. You should be able to work out an explicit isomorphism for yourself.

Comment: It could be useful to split this into 3 questions

Comment: I have just seen that in the first case, it follows from a more general fact. If $f:\text{aut}(V)\to\text{aut}(V)$ automorphism and $\varphi_2=f\circ \varphi_1$ then $V\rtimes_{\varphi_{1}} T\simeq V\rtimes_{\varphi_{2}} T.$